# java.net cannot resolve Domain name

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2, okhttp, android-networking

So, I was doing my project on localhost and everything ran smooth. I was able to make request call to the server and getting the response from my android. No problem. Then I got a ec2 from AWS and did't map to any domain name. SO, When I use curl or postman to make the request it works totally fine. Everything works great. But the same URL I try to make a request from my Retrofit it says

```
HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "ec2-11-130-81-251.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.comapi": No address associated with hostname
```

I also made sure that I have given internet permission in my phone and everything. So, is it a must to have a domain name when making network request from an android phone? is there any way to bypass such things?

here is my retrofit singleton class if it finds useful. Thanks

```
public class ApiClient {

//    public static final String BASE_LOCAL_URL = "http://192.168.1.4:3000/";
//    public static final String BASE_LOCAL_EMULATOR_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/";
        public static final String SERVIER_LOGIN="ec2-11-130-81-251.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.comapi";
    public static final String BASE_URL = SERVIER_LOGIN;

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    private ApiClient() {


        if (retrofit != null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Use getInstance() method to get the single instance of this class.");
        }
    }

    public static synchronized Retrofit getClient(Context context) {


        if (retrofit == null) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.level(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);


            AuthInterceptor authInterceptor = new AuthInterceptor(context);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().
                    addInterceptor(authInterceptor).
                    readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .build();


            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(getGson()))
                    .client(client)
                    .build();

            return retrofit;
        }


        return retrofit;
    }

    private static Gson getGson() {


        return new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").create();
    }
}
```

Comment: I resolved by adding a /in the end. Lol

Comment: If you found the answer please answer it by yourself and accept it or delete the post itself [although I personally do not recommend this because it may help others in future] so that other don't have to come to see it again beliving that it is not answered yet...

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by adding a slash in your base URL. That is if your base URL is **www.some_base_url.com** it should be **www.some_base_url.com/** when initiating a retrofit instance. So. Make sure you're adding a slash in the end if it gives that error.